# P:CommandLink doesn't work with ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have strange problem with `p:commandLink` tag when i use it with the `ui:repeat` tag !

commandLink doesn't work at all .

this my xhtml code :

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat varStatus="miteraionno" value="#{bussinessOwnerViewerMB.bOwner.bOBranches}" var="branch" >

        <div class="details" >       

        <ul class="services">
            <li>
               <p:commandLink actionListener="#{bussinessOwnerViewerMB.testMethod}" styleClass="nav_services" oncomplete="">
                    <h:outputText value="#{branch.branchName}"/>
               </p:commandLink>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </ui:repeat>
```

the ActionListener is just test method :

```
public void testMethod(){
    System.out.println("BussinessOwnerViewerMB.changeMapListener()");
}
```

i try `c:foreach` but it gives me the same result !

any help will be appreciated ..

Comment: Put the `<p:messages />` in your page for debugging purposes, you will see of any error occurred. Also I would remove `<h:ouputText />` and put it inside `<p:commandLink />` as a value parameter

Comment: I have already <p:messages/> and there is no error message appear !

I removed the <h:output ...  there is no change :(

Comment: b.t.w remove the empty `oncomplete=""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change method signature into

```
public void testMethod(ActionEvent event){
    System.out.println("BussinessOwnerViewerMB.changeMapListener()");
}
```

Or change `actionListener=...` into `action="...`

also take a look at following answer by **BalusC**

[Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909382/617373)

---

**EDIT**

Change the scope of your bean into View Scope (cause now its Request Scope)

And read bullet N#4 at the [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) by **BalusC**

Comment: thnaks daniel , but i tried al of those , my problem is not with the commandLink only "as it works fine if i put it out of the <ui: repeat> tag " the problem is appear when the commandLink render inside the ui:repeat !

Comment: what scope is your `bussinessOwnerViewerMB` bean ?

Comment: change it to view scope (atleast) , read this (bullet N#4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/617373)

Comment: Fantastic .. many thanks Daniel you made my day it works after change the scope to view scope "but i should change all related classes to implement serializable " many thanks :)